# scopes and permissions in dotnet using abp framework, permission-based authorization using scopes

Tags: .net, .net-core, permissions, abp, scopes

**Scope Permissions:**

If we have two clients accessing the same API, the first client being an admin and the second client being mobile users only, how can we set permissions based on their scopes?

The scope_admin should have permissions 1, 2, 3, and 4 by default, while the scope_mobile should have permissions 1 and 4.

**I'm trying** to add a new scope and link certain permissions to it. When a user logs in, the permissions should only be returned for their specific scope.

**Roles Permissions vs Scope Permissions?** I'm using dotnet/abp-framework

Comment: Hello, you can do the permissions in `YourProjectNamePermissionDefinitionProvider` in the app service of your related projects and the web modules of your related project.  Can you also review the relevant [document](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization)?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment .. ok but, how can we set permissions per scope, each scope has its own permissions. @onurpicakci

Comment: Please check [here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/16656).